# Triangular inequality in weighted graphs

Tags: inequality, graph-theory

In a finite directed complete graph $G ( V, E )$, if all edges have weight either $1$ or $2$, how to show that weights of edges of $G$ satisfies "**Triangular Inequality**"?

**Edited**

Where triangular inequality is weight of any edge is less than or equal to the sum of weights of any other two edges (ALWAYS)

Comment: what is the triangular inequality in this case?

Comment: Is your question: $d(u,v)+d(v,w)\geq d(u,w)$. If so, the answer below is correct.

Answer (score 1):

given an edge, it has weight 1 or 2, that is always less or equal to the sum of the weights of two edges.

This means that, if we define $d(u,v)$ as the minimum distance between the nodes $u$ and $v$, we have $1\le d(u,v)\le 2$, and so
$$d(u,v)\le 2=1+1\le d(u,w)+d(w,v)$$
 since every pair of nodes is connected by an edge.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you say what it is you are proving?

Comment: So you mean 1< either 1+1 or 1+2 ? So the proof is as simple as that?

Comment: @Technopolice Noone knows, since your question has no definition of this Triangular Inequality... That wouldn't be a proof of any defintion of the triangular inequality that I have seen though

Comment: Edited part says what I meant.